# Create a line between 2 floating divs and adjust to movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got two floating divs which can be re-positioned by the user using drag and drop.
I want to draw a line between the two divs and have it adjust itself (size and positions) to the movements of the divs.

The goal is to get some sort of chartflow/diagram alike construction within the browser.

What would be the best method to do this?

Comment: Can you post some kind of example of what you're trying to achieve, and also, what have you tried to implement to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to do anything more than *very* basic drawing/figures, then I would recommend a drawing library such as RaphaelJS. It greatly simplifies things for you. See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/RVykE/1/

That example is not a perfect implementation, but it shows how much help you get from Raphael.

Answer (score 1):

JS Plumb:

http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html

[image]

SVG, Canvas, or VML

Jquery, Mootools, or YUI

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll definately check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using just HTML, jQuery and some trigonometry!
Still needs a bit of tweaking but it's mostly there.

http://jsfiddle.net/gKj35/2/

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three ways:

1. you can use svg
2. you can use html canvas
3. you can use pure html( divs with height = 1 will be horizontal lines,
   and divs with width = 1 will be vertical lines). You can combine these lines to create a line segment.